# why can a parameter sent with GET survive several requests?

Tags: html, http, jsp, servlets

In my JSP file I have a HTML form that sends data via GET to my servlet.

```
<form method="GET">
      <input name="cmd" type="hidden" value="firstValue"/>
      .....
</form>
```

If I now trigger a different form having also a variable called `cmd`, but using POST, the old `cmd` value will stay in the parameter list I can read out in my servlet like this: `request.getParameterValues("cmd")`.

```
<form method="POST">
      <input name="cmd" type="hidden" value="secondValue"/>
      .....
</form>
```

Why can the GET parameters survive several requests? Where/how are the they stored in contrast to the POST parameters in the servlet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When not specified, the form's `action` URL defaults to the current request URL as you see in browser's address bar, including the query string. If you'd like to avoid that, explicitly specify the `action` URL.

Comment: +1 Correct answer ;) Let's just add for the sake of clarity and in case it wasn't clear already from what @BalusC wrote, that this action URL **can** point to the same address, stripped for URI parameters that aren't needed any more. Any parameters still included that match any form fields by their names will still 'survive' a GET method.